# @InjectMocks gives me null when i combine constructor injection(child class) and property injection(parent class)

Tags: java, mockito

I have an abstract with an injected property. This is extended by a child class where the injection is done via constructor. In the Unit test, the @InjectMocks gives null for the property injected in the abstract class.

See the code below.

I would like to understand why in this specific situation the @InjectMocks does not know to inject the property from the abstract class. 
Can anybody help me to understand?
Thanks a lot!!!

If both child and parent class uses property injection, my unit test works without problems.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
  @Inject
  private D d;
  ...  
}

@RequestScoped
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
{ 
  private A a;
  private B b;
  private C c;

  @Inject
  public ConcreteClass(A a, B b, C c)
  {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }

  /**
   * CDI, no arguments constructor.
   */
  public ConcreteClass()
  {
    // CDI constructor
  }
}

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class ConcreteClassTest
{
  @Mock
  D d;

  @Mock
  A a; 

  @InjectMocks
  ConcreteClass concreteClass;  

 @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception
  {
   ...
    MockProvider.setMockForClass(A.class, a);
    MockProvider.setMockForClass(D.class, d);
    ...
  }   

  @Theory
  public void testMethod()     
  {
    ...
    concreteClass.methodXXX();
    //here if i inspect the concreteClass i see that the attribute "a" has    value and attribute "d" is null.
    ...
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the mockito documentation:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

> **Constructor injection**; the biggest constructor is chosen, then arguments are resolved with mocks declared in the test only. If the object is successfully created with the constructor, then Mockito won't try the other strategies. Mockito has decided to no corrupt an object if it has a parametered constructor.

As your constructor only has A, B, C mockito does not take care of D.
(Property or Field injection are not considered)

You could change your Constructor so that it has all 4 values and passes on D to the superclass.