# Unit testing a method of a class that has a constructor and an autowired field that needs to be mocked using mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, springrunner

I have a service class that extends another service with a constructor. This class has an autowired field and a method that I wanted to unit test using Mockito. However, I am having trouble writing a unit for it.

Let say the service looks somewhat like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService extends Service {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClient someClient;

    public SomeService(Product product, @Qualifier(Constants.SOME_BEAN) Details temp) {
        super(product, temp);
    }
    @Override
    public State create() {
        Request request = new Request();
        request.set...
        request.set..

        Status status = someClient.createTenant(request);
        ..
        .. // construct a State object and return
    }
}
```

Now, I am writing a test for this class and I am trying to unit test the method create() above. I am having trouble mocking someClient there when this method is called by my test.

The test class looks somewhat like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {
    private Detail temp;

    private SomeFacade service;

    private SomeClient someClient;

    private Product product;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        temp = mock(Details.class);
        product = mock(Product.class);
        service = spy(new SomeService(product, temp));
        someClient = mock(SomeClient.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Status status = new Status();
        status.setStatus(...);
        when(someClient.createTenant(any())).thenReturn(status);
        State state =  service.create();

        // asserts
    }
}
```

What I want to is that when I call service.create in the test above, the call 
`someClient.createTenant(request);` in the method tested should be mocked to return a value and this is something I am not able to get working. Any help?

Comment: You need to provide the mock of `someClient` to `SomeService` - either manually by passing the reference or by using Annotations. But Annotations are out of the question for now as your constructor does not have a `SomeService` parameter.

Comment: Don't `@Autowired` on properties, [`@Autowired` on the constructor.](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring) Also, you can use Mockito's [`@InjectMocks`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) to inject the mocks into your unit under test. Furthermore, define what type you expect to be passed: `when(someClient.createTennant(any(Request.class)))...`.

Comment: Another question would by why you create a `spy` on the class under test, but as your example does not cover that part it could be considered off-topic.

Comment: Curious why not explicitly inject `SomeClient` into you derived service?

Comment: @Nkosi because the code - as-is - does not allow direct injection of `SomeClient` :-)

Comment: I more meant why not refractor to exicitly inject it. I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Nkosi Could you explain more with some code?

Comment: It was already explained in the provided answer. Constructor injection.

Answer (score 5):

We can use Mockito's [`@InjectMocks`-annotation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) to inject mocks into our unit under test. For this, we also need to

- remove mock intialization from the `setup()`-method and
- annotate the mocks with [`@Mock`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mock.html)

---

Remarks:

- Instead of field injection, I would recommend [constructor injection](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mock.html). This allows, among other things, to keep the structure of the code and create the unit under test within `setup()` by manual injection
- I would also recommend to add a type to the `when`: `when(someClient.createTennant(any(Request.class)))...`
- As was pointed out by @second, the `spy` on the unit under test is superfluous.
- Also pointed out by @second was the fact that field injection will not work if a constructor is present

Comment: Note that field injection won't work as long as a construtor is present (see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091389/injectmocks-gives-me-null-when-i-combine-constructor-injectionchild-class-and/57093368#57093368)

Comment: `... the spy on the unit under test is superfluous.` -- I recently had a discussion with some people who consider that `bad smell`. There can be reasons for that however they are not mentioned in the example.

Comment: @second let's continue this discussion in [chat]

Comment: I think I need to understand this better. At this time, I cannot really change the constructor. Can I still unit test and mock that call? Some code for my example will help understand better, if possible

Comment: @user1892775 I linked the mockito documentation. It includes an example. I also wrote a two-point list for what to do. I will not refactor the test for you, sorry.

Comment: Upvote for recommendation of constructor injection and for typing the call to `any`

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to use @InjectMocks and @Mock.
Let's init your target class by using constructor

```
i.e: 
Product product = Mockito.mock(Product.class);
...
SomeService service = new SomeService(product,...);
```

Then use ReflectionTestUtils to init @Autowire fields by Mockito class

```
i.e:
SomeClient someClient = Mockito.mock(SomeClient.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "someClient", someClient);
```